# How can I set Firefox's viewport to a width of less than 450px?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm trying to run some automated tests with Selenium in Firefox in normal view (not headless). I want to set the viewport to `width=375, height=812` (iPhone X), but starting on Firefox 75 they set the minimum width to 450px ([Firefox bug tracker](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1610497)).

I've read [some posts](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/fjkma4/firefox_740_minimum_window_width/fknfk9f) saying you can use the `userChrome.css` file to modify this setting but they only seem to work on Linux and not on macOS nor Windows 10.

**How can I force Firefox to allow me to set a viewport of less than 450px?**

Comment: Did you find any solution for this problem. Tried also the userChrome.css, only works when using the firefox directly but didn't work in headless mode there still is the limit of 450px.

Comment: No, tried everything and couldn't do it. I ended up just downgrading to Firefox 74 for what I wanted to do.

Comment: I encountered this problem, too. It seems to depend on the specific HTML or CSS used, but it's too complicated for me to figure out since I am using Bootstrap 5. The developer tools don't give css rules for min-width, so imaybe it's a bug in both Firefox and Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to create a `profile.zip` with the `chrome/userChrome.css` with the following content:

```css
#main-window:not([chromehidden~="toolbar"]) {
    min-width: 50px !important;
}
```

and a `user.js` with the following content:

```js
user_pref("toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets", true);
```

The profile.zip need to be given as a base64 encoded string to the remote web driver. Not sure how this is done in selenium.

**PHP Web Driver Solution**

Lot of spaghetti code but this is what worked for me using php web-driver library. Creating a profile and unpack the profile again and then add the `userChrome.css`. Tested on macOS:

```php
// create firefox profile zip
$profileZipPath = __DIR__ . '/profile.zip';
$firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
$firefoxProfile->setPreference('toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets', true);
$firefoxProfile = $firefoxProfile->encode();
file_put_contents($profileZipPath, base64_decode($firefoxProfile));
 
// unpack profile zp
$zip = new \ZipArchive();
$zip->open($profileZipPath);
$profilePath = __DIR__ . '/profile';
$zip->extractTo($profilePath);

// add chrome/userChrome.css
$cssDirectory = $profilePath . '/chrome';
mkdir($cssDirectory);
file_put_contents($cssDirectory . '/userChrome.css', <<<EOT
#main-window:not([chromehidden~="toolbar"]) {
    min-width: 50px !important;
}
EOT
);

// create profile zip
$zip = new \ZipArchive();
$zip->open($profileZipPath, \ZipArchive::CREATE);

$dir = new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator($profilePath);
$files = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir);

$dir_prefix = preg_replace(
    '#\\\\#',
    '\\\\\\\\',
    $profilePath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
);

foreach ($files as $name => $object) {
    if (is_dir($name)) {
         continue;
    }

    $path = preg_replace("#^{$dir_prefix}#", '', $name);
    $zip->addFile($name, $path);
}
$zip->close();

// use the new profile
$firefoxProfile = base64_encode(file_get_contents($profileZipPath));
$capabilities = DesiredCapabilities::firefox();
$capabilities->setCapability(FirefoxDriver::PROFILE => $firefoxProfile);

// ...
```